# Print names alphabetically and how many appearances for each name

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that includes names, one on each line. I want to print the names alphabetically, but (and here is where it gets confusing at least for me) next to each name I must print the number of appearances of that name with exactly one space between the name and the number of appearances.

For example if the file includes these names:

```
Barry
Don
John
Sam
Harry
Don
Don 
Sam
```

it must print

```
Barry 1
Don 3
Harry 1
John 1
Sam 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort | uniq -c` will get you very close, just with the columns reversed.

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
      1 Barry
      3 Don
      1 Harry
      1 John
      2 Sam
```

If you really need them in the proscribed order you could swap them with `awk`.

```
$ sort test.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'
Barry 1
Don 3
Harry 1
John 1
Sam 2
```

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
% awk '{
  a[$1]++
}
END{
  for (i in a) {
    print i, a[i]
  }
}' file
```

#### Output:

```
Barry 1
Harry 1
Don 3
John 1
Sam 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file
Barry
Don
John
Sam
Harry
Don
Don 
Sam
```

You can do:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++} END { for (e in a) print e, a[e] }' file | sort 
Barry 1
Don 3
Harry 1
John 1
Sam 2
```

Comment: Your original has the output on a single line. If that is what you want, you can do `awk '{a[$1]++} END { for (e in a) print e, a[e] } ' file | sort | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: that was my bad the answer must be in multiple lines